# How can I get the vendor ID and product ID for a USB device?

Tags: usb

Where can I find the vendor ID and product ID for a USB device? They are given by the company who manufactured the USB, right?

Comment: Somewhat related app note by FTDI: [USB Vendor ID / Product ID Guidelines](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_100_USB_VID-PID_Guidelines.pdf).

Comment: You want to get these IDs for a device you have, or you want to create a new device?

Comment: @EugeneSh. For a device I have

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**On Windows:** Assuming your device is connected to the computer, go to "**Device manager**", find your device, right click on it, select "**Properties**", go to "**Details**" tab, select "**Hardware IDs**" from the drop-down, and you will find an entry of a form:

```
HID\VID_046D&PID_C05A
```

which are correspondingly vendor and product IDs.

**On Linux**:  Run the following command from your terminal:

```
lsusb
```

You will see pairs `VID:PID` near the names of all of the USB devices connected..

Comment: One can also install `lsusb` on a Mac using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to get this information.

Answer (score 4):

#### How can I get the vendor id and the PID for a USB device?

If you are running Windows then you can [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/).

Screenshot showing VendorID and ProductID (PID):

[image]

> USBDeview is a small utility that lists all USB devices that currently connected to your computer, as well as all USB devices that you previously used.
>
> For each USB device, extended information is displayed: Device name/description, device type, serial number (for mass storage devices), the date/time that device was added, VendorID, ProductID, and more...
>
> USBDeview also allows you to uninstall USB devices that you previously used, disconnect USB devices that are currently connected to your computer, as well as to disable and enable USB devices.
>
> You can also use USBDeview on a remote computer, as long as you login to that computer with admin user.

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way; I am just an end user of their software.