# Plugging in power bank makes USB plug in sound

Tags: windows, usb

When I plug the AmazonBasics Portable PowerBank to the USB2 port in my ASUS motherboard, Windows 10 will make the usual USB plug-in sound after a second or two.

This does not happen with other power banks I own so I'm wondering why this is happening with this one. Why is Windows recognizing it as a USB device and trying to initialize its driver when it should just be a "dumb" power bank?

I could open it and inspect what's inside but I wanted to check first if I should be paranoid or if this is normal for some USB power banks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is Windows recognizing it as a USB device and trying to initialize its driver when it should just be a "dumb" power bank?

If I remember correctly: In traditional USB, a device can only expect 100 mA when it is connected, and can only expect the full 500 mA after it has identified itself.

As far as I know chargers bypass this by using additional protocols to negotiate the power supply (e.g. QuickCharge or USB Battery Charging spec), but a typical computer's USB 2.0 port is very unlikely to speak any of those, so the power bank has to use the regular mechanism.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. now that I know what to look for, this seems related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/how-to-get-more-than-100ma-from-a-usb-port

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

- Open Device Manager from the Control Panel.
- Expand all trees.
- Plug in the device.
- See what new device appears.

It's possible this is done on purpose so that any power management enables the port and allows the power bank to charge.

Comment: it shows as unrecognized device

Comment: Now do this: https://superuser.com/questions/1106247/how-can-i-get-the-vendor-id-and-product-id-for-a-usb-device#1106248